# Delete column from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

- `PROJECT` with (id_project PK, Name, Timestamp)
- `MEASUREMENT OF PROJECT` with (Measurement_ID, Project_ID FK, Measurement_id_project PK)

One project can be associated with several measurements.

How can I create a query to delete on project selected by ID and the related measurements associated with it?

Comment: Um, 2 delete statements inside a transaction?

Comment: And please only tag the *actual* version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: ops sorry, i was thinking to do 2 statement but is not another method?

Comment: No, you can verify that from the documentation, delete only works on a single table.

Comment: Is ON DELETE CASCADE an option?

Comment: Do you want to delete some project one time, or many times? And can you allowed to alter constraints?

Comment: @Serg i was seeing on delete cascade but i don't know how use it. Pls help me

Comment: What have you tried, what issues do you face?

Comment: I've used ON CASCADE